# Merging two mySQL databases by hour

Tags: mysql, google-analytics

So I have two MySQL tables:

- One is a Google analytics table with how many sessions happened each hour.
- The other table is a list of the events that were happening on that site at specific times.

On the analytics table there is *one row for every hour*, but on the events table there are many gaps.

I want to add a column to the events table that shows how many sessions occurred during each event and just ignore the sessions taking place without an event.

Comment: I suggest you break out your date into date and hour, and link the two tables on date & hour.  Use a select to get your results.  (e.g. SELECT A.*,SUM(B.Hits) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.DATE = B.DATE AND A.HOUR = B.HOUR GROUP BY A.*).

Comment: @Kellen Garret Providing the DDL of each table would be useful for getting an accurate answer.